# What is the max length of a SOSL search expression?

Tags: apex, sosl, search

My SOSL query with an extremely long search expression failed with

> System.UnexpectedException: Search Term exceeded max length

Searching the Documentation I could not find anything about a max length. Do you know of such and do you know its value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

20,000 characters as of the Summer '13 release.

https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf - page 37

> The SOSL statement character limit is tied to the SOQL statement
>   character limit defined for your organization. By default, SOQL and
>   SOSL queries cannot exceed 20,000 characters.